# Azure ADB2C cookie size, how to reduce?

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-ad-b2c

Our Web app is using Azure ADB2C for Identity Management and is generating a cookie which is **2044** bytes.

The sample ADB2C web app @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app generates a cookie that is **944** bytes.

What does the cookie hold and how can I reduce the size of the cookie in our web app to be of a similar size or smaller than the B2C sample app?

Answer (score 0):

This application cookie contains the identity claims that are issued by the Azure AD B2C policy.

If you have [created an Azure AD B2C policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app#create-policies) that includes a large number of claims in the ID token, then the application cookie will be large.